# npm start giving error in node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

i am totally new to node.js and mongodb. I am using the following link: http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/ 
This procedure worked very fine and got the exact same results. But all of a sudden "npm start" stopped working. 
I uninstalled every thing and trying to re-install from step 1 given in this tutorial. when i give the command "npm install -g express" i am not getting any list of http 304's and GETS!! . 
As i ignore and continue the procedure, i give the command npm start , but it does not work. the error displayed is shown below
      C:\project\nodetest1>npm start

```
  > nodetest1@0.0.0 start C:\project\nodetest1
  > node ./bin/www


   npm ERR! nodetest1@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
   npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the nodetest1@0.0.0 start script.
   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the nodetest1 package,
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
   npm ERR! You can get their info via:
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls nodetest1
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
   npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
   npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
  npm ERR! cwd C:\project\nodetest1
  npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
  npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
  npm ERR! syscall spawn
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno ENOENT
  npm ERR! nodetest1@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
  npm ERR! Exit status -1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the nodetest1@0.0.0 start script.
  npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the nodetest1 package,
  npm ERR! not with npm itself.
  npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
  npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
  npm ERR! You can get their info via:
  npm ERR!     npm owner ls nodetest1
  npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
  npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
  npm ERR! cwd C:\project\nodetest1
  npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
  npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
  npm ERR!     C:\project\nodetest1\npm-debug.log
  npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Please help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of `C:\project\nodetest1\bin\www` for us? The problem could well be something in that file.

Comment: @kow turned out  I needed `sudo ./mongod` to run first....

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that the ./bin/www directory is not found. Paths specified with a dot are relative to the current directory, so your current directory has to be C:/project/nodetest1 for `npm start` to work in this case.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But .bin/www directory is present within c:/project/nodetest1/bin only. but still the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here.

First, you should upgrade to a newer `npm`, as the `npm` that ships with even the latest version of `node` is out of date.  To upgrade `npm` on Windows, follow the instructions here:
https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

Second, you may need to do some more troubleshooting on your own to find the problem.  `npm start` just follows the instructions in the `package.json`.  The package.json is telling `npm` that `start` means "run node ./bin/www".

What happens when you run that same script from the command line?

> cd C:\project\nodetest1
>   node ./bin/www

Does the file 'bin/www' exist?  Is node installed and in your path?  These are the issues that you will have to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you for reply Sam Mikes. But I am getting that path specified is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Delete the node_modules folder.
Run `npm install`
And then, re-run your command `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

**The package.json is telling npm that start means "run node ./bin/www".**
**but packege.json predefined staring script is npm run serve **

please try this one.

**npm run serve**

`"start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\""`

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible situation causing this problem might be that the command `npm start` is giving error is because the current directory that you are in right now and the react app directory is not same. Try navigating your command prompt to the react app location using `cd ./your react app location/`