# npm start hangs on start, says specified procedure couldn't be found, verbose exit status 3221225786

Tags: node.js, npm, bson

When I ran npm start a few months ago, everything worked fine. Now npm start hangs and says the error message in the picture. The file is there though when I followed the breadcrumbs so the error isn't helpful nor correct. I tried to follow this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794932/npm-start-giving-error-in-node-js)
and update everything but it still hangs. I have put the npm-debug.log below. Googling the error exit status did not bear fruit either. Any ideas?

[image]

The following comes from npm-debug.log (hopefully it helps cause I'm lost):

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.11.1
3 info using node@v0.12.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart flapper-news@0.0.0
6 info start flapper-news@0.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info flapper-news@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script
9 verbose stack Error: flapper-news@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
9 verbose stack Exit status 3221225786
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
10 verbose pkgid flapper-news@0.0.0
11 verbose cwd C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\flapper-news
12 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
13 error argv "node" "C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
14 error node v0.12.4
15 error npm  v2.11.1
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error flapper-news@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
17 error Exit status 3221225786
18 error Failed at the flapper-news@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the flapper-news package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     node ./bin/www
18 error You can get their info via:
18 error     npm owner ls flapper-news
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```